# How do I convert Date into DateComponents in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, datepicker, notifications, uikit, swiftui

I want to set a daily notification at the time a user selects from a DatePicker, but I can't figure out how to convert the selected hour and minute into DateComponents to match the UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.

This is my DatePicker:

```
DatePicker("Choose time of notif", selection: $notifTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
```

This is my notification trigger:

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents = notifTime
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to get the `dateComponents` from the `date` property using the `Calendar` API, that needs to be repeated. So, in this case, the hour and minute repeats everyday so here's how you do this:

```
var notifTime: Date
let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: notifTime)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
```